# Bootstrap table: Exclude ID column from being sorted

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Is it possible to exclude ID column from being sorted when other columns are being sorted? (to avoid the IDs messed up)

here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjykowtL/27/)

HTML:

```
<table id="summaryTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-align="center" data-width="20px" >id</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-field="type" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use CSS counter to display row numbers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Answer (score 1):

I found the best answer that works as I needed in my case, to use `data-formater`. Works with pagination, with the filter input and with the column sorting.

Everything is [here](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/441).

It is simply to add a function:

```
function runningFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to have the numbering in the "id column" generated based on row index - rather than content **if the displayed id of the row is not important**. You can still have the actual row of the content as a data-attribute of the first td, so that you can isolate the row content or pass the data back to the back end - its just that the displayed row index will be generated as a sequential list of rows that always appears to be correctly numbered - irrespective of the row order.

Note that I have got the buttons actually recreating the table on their click - this is NOT how you would do it, but is there only to demonstrate the renumber of the row index - whilst the actual index order is maintained in the data attribute of the first td.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
numberRows();
   
  $('#sortButtonUp').click(function(){
    $('#summaryTable tbody').html('<tr><td class="generatedID" data-actualID = "2"></td><td>Susan</td> <td>Admin</td></tr><tr><td class="generatedID" data-actualID = "1"></td> <td>Bob</td> <td>Customer</td></tr>');
    numberRows();
    })
  
     
  $('#sortButtonDown').click(function(){
    $('#summaryTable tbody').html('<tr><td class="generatedID" data-actualID = "1"></td> <td>Bob</td> <td>Customer</td></tr><tr><td class="generatedID" data-actualID = "2"></td><td>Susan</td> <td>Admin</td></tr>');
    numberRows();
    })
  })

  function numberRows(){
   $('.generatedID').each(function(index){
    $(this).text(index +1);
    })
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="summaryTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="generatedID" data-actualID = "1"></td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Customer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="generatedID" data-actualID = "2"></td>
      <td>Susan</td>
      <td>Admin</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
<button type = "button" id = "sortButtonUp" >Sort Name up</button>
<button type = "button" id = "sortButtonDown" >Sort Name Down</button>
```

Comment: so, probably I would have to use inside the event function to number rows again: `$('#summaryTable').on('sort.bs.table', function (e, name, order) {

    $('#summaryTable tr').each(function(index){
      $(this).find("td").text(index+1);  
    });
});` but even that this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

My idea to maintain fixed a column during the [table column sort process](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) is based on:

- a global variable to save the table data before the sort starts (i.e.: onSort event) in order to have the data unordered for the involved column
- use the previous data on table rendering (i.e.: onPreBody event) to reset the ordering on the column of your interest

My snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var t = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "john", "type": "car"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "ted0", "type": "house"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "ted1", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "4", "name": "ted2", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "5", "name": "ted3", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "6", "name": "ted4", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "7", "name": "ted5", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "8", "name": "ted6", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "9", "name": "ted7", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "10", "name": "ted8", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "11", "name": "ted9", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "12", "name": "ted10", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "13", "name": "ted11", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "14", "name": "ted12", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "15", "name": "ted13", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "16", "name": "ted14", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "17", "name": "ted15", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "18", "name": "ted16", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "19", "name": "ted17", "type": "bike"},
    {"id": "20", "name": "ted18", "type": "bike"},
  ];


    //TABLE 1
    var savedData = null;
    $('#summaryTable').bootstrapTable({
      data: t,
      onSort: function(name, order) {
        savedData =   $('#summaryTable').bootstrapTable('getData').map(function(element, index) {
          return element.id;
        });
      },
      onPreBody: function (args) {
        if (savedData != null) {
          args.forEach(function(element, index) {
            element.id = savedData[index];
          });
          savedData = null;
        }
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <p>TABLE 1</p>
    <table id="summaryTable" data-pagination="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-align="center" data-width="20px" data-sortable="false">id</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
            <th data-field="type" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">type</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've been testing this and so far is the best answer, but I've ran into a problem with this. I load data with ajax from DB using this function: `$("#summaryTable").bootstrapTable("load", data);` in ajax success function. If I first do the sorting and add some value to DB, then I want to refresh data in the table by calling the mentioned above function I get IDs messed up again. IDs are created in php while fetching data from query result and sent with other data at once. Bootstrap-table loads data as the table sort is set up, soo...any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @soonic I'm sorry, but I cannot understand. In my fiddle all works fine.Also, I tried to load dynamically like you say, but nothing fails.  So, the only way to help you is: could you create a fiddle to simulate your problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: well, I'll try to create a fiddle to simulate the problem later, but I think I would need just a function for now which would just loop through rows and assign index again because If I load data with more rows then it ID column needs to be reassigned again so after data load or data sort I'd call this function.

Comment: Well, I'll wait for the fiddle. Because, without a real case I cannot understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: thanks for trying, I just found the answer to my question and posted here.